# do-release-upgrade with held packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

When trying to `do-release-upgrade` I get the "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading". The thing is that I deliberately held some packages (with `apt-mark hold ..`) because those are the latest, which work correctly in the setup I need to keep working. All the answers I've seen so far concentrate on "how to upgrade packages inadvertently kept back so that `do-release-upgrade` does not complain anymore". I know how to do this and this does not solve the problem. I *need* to keep those packages back but would still like to upgrade the distribution. Any hints?

I know that I could probably keep the `.debs` and try downgrading held packages after `do-release-upgrade` but I hoped for a command-line switch or so.

Comment: The upgrade tool is intended to not-work with held packages, as that's a pretty sure sign that problems will occur; thus it flags itself & refuses to continue. Possibly the only way maybe to upgrade the packages, perform the *release-upgrade*, then reboot, and on the new release return the packages to the older version if it's possible (it's very likely not possible, or at least very unwise, the safest option being to remain on your currently *unstated* release).  You know what packages you mean, so you can see the consequences, something we cannot as we don't know the package(s).

Comment: I see. I'll have to dig those original package files out. Should still have them somewhere, thanks.

Comment: The intended usage of the tool is just a sign of how dumb is deb world. Being compatible is the job of a correct dependency resolver (and dependency descriptions), not some arbitrary prohibition.

Answer (score 6):

For third-party (PPA) packages simple way is to remove sources (`rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appropriate-source.list`, or comment out contents). Once there is no possible source, there is also no missing update. And such sources would be disabled during upgrade,

Comment: In my case they were base packages so this wouldn't work but it might in fact be useful for someone with PPA packages. Tnx and upvote

Answer (score -2):

Best to do apt package pinning for this.
Example if we want to pin to exact version 5.14.0-6578:

Get available versions (you could use your dpkg --list | grep sensu)

```
apt-cache madison sensu-go-backend
```

vim /etc/apt/preferences.d/sensu

```
Package: sensu-go-backend
Pin: version 5.14.0-6578
Pin-Priority: 999
```

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: The question was't about pinning, it was about **how to do a release upgrade with pinned packages**, something that isn't possible by design (and common sense). You may have noticed - if you didn't you should - the comment below the question, some 8 months ago: *The upgrade tool is intended to not-work with held packages, as that's a pretty sure sign that problems will occur; thus it flags itself & refuses to continue.*